# Celestron uncommon DC long barrel connector

Tags: telescope

I have tried to connect a 12v DC adaptor and also a battery pack to my telescope unsuccessfully. Sadly it seems Celestron DC jack needs to be around 2mm longer than common 5525 DC ports.
I was wondering what are **those barrel connectors called** so I can google it to find a male to male cable that is compatible.
And if Celestron is using an uncommon port to make customers buy its products or there is a technical reason for that?

Celestron DC5525 connector with ~14mm head.

[image]

Celestron DC5525 connector with 10mm head

[image]

I found this amazing illustration

[image]

Comment: Can you add any details? to what you are plugging in to? Which model and/or year of the  "Celestron" (I assume it's the computer drive on one of their telescopes, but it could be some other product of theirs) If the box also has a model number that would be helpful too. Sometimes electronics comes with different connectors in different regions of the world as well.

Comment: There's also Electronics SE but they will demand some details for sure.

Comment: There are power supplies with multiple adapters (e.g. https://www.amazon.com/Belker-Universal-Adapter-Supply-Speaker/dp/B07N18XN84/ref=sr_1_6?dchild=1&keywords=power+adapter&qid=1612729883&sr=8-6) One of them might fit your telescope